# How many methods are there to find the inverse of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, soft-question

I am an undergraduate math student.
I have found in my books there are only $2$ or $3$ methods of finding the inverse of matrix which are possibly row transformation, Gauss-Jordan elimination and the general adjoint/determinant method.

What I am wondering is matrix seems to be a art which is developed and I guess is still developing time to time. Can anyone provide any other methods to find inverse of matrix ?

Also let me know which method is faster. Some reference links or books are expected.

Have a nice day.

Comment: When the matrix has an inverse, computing the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) gives you the inverse.

Comment: While it doesn't answer your question, I would point out that there are many many algorithms for solving linear systems which do not compute a matrix inverse. That is because computing the inverse to a matrix is not stable.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Methods_of_matrix_inversion)? Presumably, this list is not exhaustive, and that there are many other methods that work for matrices with some specific structure. (For example, I doubt you would try any of these methods when your matrix is diagonal.) Querying Google with "matrix inversion algorithm" also returns many results.